# Foreach substitute in Linq

Tags: c#, excel, linq, epplus

I have a query that I want to substitue the `foreach` with linq because the `foreach` is so slow
how can I write all this codein one query
this is my code:

```
    ret = new List<ReportData>();
    foreach (var item in Number)
    {
        string A = item.Substring(0, 11);
        string B = item.Substring(14, 2);
        string C = item.Substring(19, 11);
        string D = item.Substring(33);
        ret1 = (from a in Report
                where a.A == A && a.B == B && a.C == C && a.D == D && Filter.Type.Contains(a.Y) 
                select new ReportData
                {
                    X = a.X,
                    Y = a.Y,
                });
       if (ret1 != null && ret1.ToList().Count > 0)
          {
             ret.AddRange(ret1);
          }       
}
```

Comment: what is `Number`? Furthermore LINQ won´t make your code faster, just not that greedy (memory).

Comment: Currently your code only keeps the result produced from the last item in `Number`.

Comment: As you overwrite `ret` on each pass of the `foreach` loop, you can keep the same functionality and make it a lot faster by only processing the last element of the weirdly named `Number`.

Comment: @user3122648 No, you replace `ret` on each iteration as David Arno says and thus your code only keeps the result from the last item in `Number`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Number is the table I am searching in

Comment: Why are you doing ret1.ToList()> 0 why aren't you doing ret1.Any(). Also what is Filter.Type is it a list or a  HashSet ?

Comment: I editted my question

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, LINQ will not make a foreach any faster; if you have to iterate the entire collection, then foreach will be faster than LINQ.

There is no need to check for null or if any results exists in the inner LINQ statement; just add the range since the LINQ query will return an `Enumerable.Empty<ReportData>` if nothing is returned from the query.

```
if (ret1 != null && ret1.ToList().Count > 0)
{
  ret.AddRange(ret1);
}   
// becomes
ret.AddRange(ret1);
```

Assumming `Number` is a collection of string, make sure there are no duplicates:

```
foreach (string item in Number.Distinct())
```

If `Number` is a large list, thousands of items or more, then consider using a [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Linq will just enumerate the collection just like a `foreach` would, but you *might* see some benefit from a `join`:

```
var items = Number.Select( item => new {
    A = item.Substring(0, 11),
    B = item.Substring(14, 2),
    C = item.Substring(19, 11),
    D = item.Substring(33),
    });

var ret = (from a in Report
           join i in items
           on new {a.A, a.B, a.C, a.D} equals new {i.A, i.B, i.C, i.D}  
           where Filter.Type.Contains(a.Y) 
           select new ReportData
           {
               X = a.X,
               Y = a.Y,
           });
```

Comment: from a in Report
           join i in items
           on new {a.A, a.B, a.C, a.D} equals new {i.A, i.B, i.C, i.D}.....................  
because I want to search each item (in items) in Report

Comment: @user3122648 Is that a question?  The join will line up each report with the matching item(s)